# How to change the view for open programs in the taskbar in KDE?

Tags: kde, panel, taskbar, kde5

[image: A screen-shot of my dual-monitors]

I am using KDE Plasma 5. Look at the panels at the bottom. They are from the attached monitor on the right, and my laptop on the left. They have full tab sized sets for the programs that I've opened. I don't want them in that way. I want the panel/taskbar to have just icons of the open programs with maybe a counter on top of them to represent the number of instances open of the specific program. How do I achieve this in KDE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click the `Hamburger`-icon at the right end of the panel, remove the 'Task Manager'-widget, then click `Add Widgets`, scroll the widget-list down to find the `Icons-only Task Manager`-widget and drag it to the panel.