# Icons only in Kubuntu panel

Tags: kubuntu, panel

My wife told me her Panel was wonky this evening.  Turns out her System Tray was pushed to the left, next to the Application Launcher.  I was finally able to move it back to the right, but now the application icons have no descriptions in the Panel.  I'm sure there's a simple setting I'm missing, but for the life of me I can't find it.

Comment: Please specify the version of Kubuntu you are facing issue with

Comment: Sorry about that.  It's Kubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Please take a look at this question (https://askubuntu.com/questions/914886/how-to-change-the-view-for-open-programs-in-the-taskbar-in-kde/914896#914896), there it is just the other way around.